# MKStoreKit and iOS 5

Tags: ios5, mkstorekit

I've been using MKStoreKit to enable in-app purchases in my apps. The latest binary I submitted using this method was rejected because nothing happens when the user clicks on the purchase button when the reviewer tested it on iOS 5. Is this an iOS 5 issues, or has something else gone wonky? It works fine when I test it on iOS 4.
My iPod is too old to upgrade to iOS 5 and I've started saving up to buy a new one, but I'd like to get this app on the store before then. Also, it means that several of my other apps will be broken and I would like to fix those as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special in MKStoreKit that could probably break on iOS 5. I've used it in many apps running iOS 4 and 5 without any issues. Can you test it on a real device and post what happens?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update this. Apple was just explaining it really badly. It wasn't the purchase button where nothing happened, it was the cancel button after they click purchase. I had forgotten to add the callback.